# How to play an audio file without it opening in a new tab

Tags: javascript, wordpress, audio, preventdefault

I would like to implement an audio player on all of my WordPress pages and therefore I need to create the HTML element with JS and manipulate it from there. Everything is working, except for when I press the play button, it redirects me to a new page with the audio link and plays it there. I would like to prevent that, so that I can play and stop it on the WP pages themselves and have the audio play in the background.

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

```
function addAudioPlayer() {

  const audioPlayer = document.createElement("a");
  audioPlayer.setAttribute("id", "audioPlayer");
  audioPlayer.href =
    "https://www.hostname.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/bird_sound.wav";
  audioPlayer.setAttribute("data-id", "[data-song]");
  audioPlayer.innerHTML = "&#9654;";
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-song]"),
    function (song) {

      song.audio = new Audio(song.href);
      
      song.setAttribute("role", "button");
      song.setAttribute("aria-pressed", "false");
    }
  );
  document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

      if (!event.target.hasAttribute("data-song")) return;

      event.preventDefault();

      if (event.target.getAttribute("aria-pressed") == "true") {
        event.target.audio.pause();
        event.target.setAttribute("aria-pressed", "false");
        return;
      }
      event.target.audio.play();
      event.target.setAttribute("aria-pressed", "true");
    },
    false
  );
  document.body.appendChild(audioPlayer);
}
```

Comment: use an [<audio> Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

Comment: Have you try setting the target attribute to the newly created <a> tag to "_self"?

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you, that solves it, but I want to keep my simple audio player with no controls, only the play button, which is not possible when I use the <audio> tag.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez I just did and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: hide controls, and make your own play button

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div> 
    <audio id="myaudio" src="https://www.hostname.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/bird_sound.wav" controls="controls"  preload="auto" hidden="true"></audio>
    <input type="button" onclick="autoPlay()" value="Play"/>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var myAuto = document.getElementById('myaudio');
        function autoPlay(){
            myAuto.play();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).